# How to multiply two columns in a user-filled table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made table in a js with two columns A and B, with possibility to write some numbers into its cells. After filling this table i need to multiply numbers in a row and write the result into another column.

I am able to multiply two inputs with result in another textbox using HTML + JS, but i don't know how to work with the JS table and the cycle, to multiply each two cells in a row.

```
**var** table = document.getElementById('tab');

**for** (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
{
    result = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1]) * 
     parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[2] );
}

document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = "multiply:" + result;
console.log(result);
```

Console shows NaN, and I dont know if the reference on the table can be used that way, if the table is made in JS editor not HTML.

Comment: Try changing `table.rows[i].cells[1]` to `table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML`. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_tr_cells.asp.

Comment: Thanks, but still not multiplying. Write error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at editorr.js:27. Do i have to use brackets ?

Comment: That should have worked. I tried it out and it worked for me. See here for reference: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7MPGLK8IVF8

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of using var table, it is better to use var tablename. table could or could not be a reserved keyword but we can better name a table as tablename.